# How to add entirely new fields to queried Firestore (autoID) document from an Android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an Android app that lets users query the database by inputting a phone number. The search is returned with the username linked with the phone number, much like truecaller.

This is what the Firestore database structure currently looks like:

collection("contact")---document(auto generated ID)---(field1 ("username"), field2 ("phoneNum"))

This is my code:

```
CollectionReference collectionReference = db.collection("contact");
Query query = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("phoneNum",phonesearch);
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>(){
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task){
      if (task.isSuccessful()) {
      for (DocumentSnapshot document:task.getResult()){

      username = document.getString("username");
      phonenum = document.getString("phonenum");

      //storing the searcher username in the database
      Map<String, String> Usermap = new HashMap<>();
      searcher = user.getDisplayName();
      Usermap.put("searcher", searcher);
      db.collection("contact").add(Usermap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {  

    }
 });
```

How best can I save the username(s) of searchers who search for phone numbers, so the owners of the phone numbers can get notified whenever someone searches for their number? It should look like this:

collection("contact")---document(auto generated ID)---(field1 ("username"), field2 ("phone number"), field3 ("searcher1"), field4 ("searcher2"),.....fieldN("searcher3"))

currently it creates an entirely new document. I don't want it to do so, I just want it to add the new field (searcher) to the existing document.

Other solutions would be appreciated also. Thanks.

................................................This is what it looks like after the changes, it overwrites the previous searcher username with the most recent one, instead of updating the list with the latest searcher username.

```
Map<String, Object> Usermap = new HashMap<>();
searcher = user.getDisplayName();
Usermap.put("searcher", searcher);
db.collection("contact").document(document.getId()).update(Usermap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                }
                            });
```

[database photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cprak.png)
[database photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2n9N.png)

The second screenshot might look confusing...it's because fields are arranged in alphabetical order. Searcher field is an array type, by now it's meant to have about 3 usernames under it but it keeps deleting the previous one and replacing it with the most current one, thats why it still has only one user Id in it.

Comment: You can add ArrayLists as fields AFAIK. Why not do that and just update it when needed?

Comment: Are you using Firebase authentication?

Comment: @TheWander I've edited the question and added code so it can be clearer.

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes I'm using Firebase authentication.

Comment: Will be helpful for you if I provide you an answer that contains a change in your database schema?

Comment: Yes, please do. looks like i have no other choice.

Comment: Hello @AlexMamo , i still haven't found a way around it...can you help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It adds a new document because you are using CollectionReference's [add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.html#add(java.lang.Object)) method:

> Adds a new document to this collection with the specified POJO as contents, assigning it a document ID automatically.

Instead of using DocumentReference's [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#update(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) method:

> Updates fields in the document referred to by this DocumentReference.

So in order to solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
db.collection("contact").add(Usermap).addOnSuccessListener
```

to

```
db.collection("contact").document(document.getId()).update(String.valueOf(Usermap), searches).addOnSuccessListener(/* ... */);
```

To store those searches, I recommend you create another object (map) named `searches` and store all those searches beneath it. Don't store each search as a separate property. Your schema should look like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- contact (collection)
         |
         --- autoGeneratedId (document)
                |
                --- username: "User Name"
                |
                --- phoneNumber: +123456789
                |
                --- searches
                      |
                      --- searcher1: true
                      |
                      --- searcher2: true
```

There is also an approach in which you can store all those searches into an `array`. This is how your database structure should look like:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- contact (collection)
         |
         --- autoGeneratedId (document)
                |
                --- username: "User Name"
                |
                --- phoneNumber: +123456789
                |
                --- searches: ["searcher1", "searcher2"]
```

Remember, this solutions will work fine only of you'll store a limited number of searches. If you think that the number of searches will be much more that a document can hold, in that case please consider create a collection of searches like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- contact (collection)
         |
         --- autoGeneratedId (document)
                |
                --- username: "User Name"
                |
                --- phoneNumber: +123456789
                |
                --- searches (collection)
                      |
                      --- searcher1 (document)
                      |       |
                      |       --- //details
                      |
                      --- searcher2 (document)
                              |
                              --- //details
```

Comment: thanks alot for helping out...It didn't work completely as it overwrites the last searcher. I want it to update the list with the new searcher not overwrite it.

Comment: This is what `update()` method does. Please see my update answer in which I have used: `db.collection("contact").document(document.getId()).update(Usermap).addOnSuccessListener(/* ... */);` Does it work now?

Comment: That's what i used...kiindly see what my current code looks like..as i have updated my question to include my current status...

Comment: Oh, ya, you're right. My mistake, sorry about that. Should be `db.collection("contact").document(document.getId()).set(Usermap, SetOptions.merge()).addOnSuccessListener(/* ... */);` as in my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: it replaces the last searcher with the most current one...I want it to store the list of all the searchers not to replace the previous one with the most recent one.

Comment: Have you tried to use the solution in my last comment, passing `SetOptions.merge()` as the second document?

Comment: still the same...the field in the array keeps replacing itself with the most current searcher i.e it deletes the previous searcher id and replaces it with the most current one

Comment: I understand. Please show me your real database structure to see the problem more clearly.

Comment: I have taken a screenshot and added it to my question...kindly check. thanks

Comment: I see now. You have this behaviour because you are using an `array` and not a map (object) as I suggested you in my first solution in my answer. To solve this, change the type of your `searches` array to `object` and your problem will be solved. Or you can leave the `searches` as it is and update date value using `db.collection("contact").document(document.getId()).update("searches", FieldValue.arrayUnion("searcher1"));`. So, is it ok now?

Comment: Unfortunately, it hasnt worked...been trying to find why the searcher object (on firestore) changes to array type, immediately the first searcher is added...

Comment: This is also what I advised you, to use an object. Do you have an error? What is the bahaviour?

Comment: Yes, like you said, I changed the searcher field type from array to object type...what happens is, immediately i update the searcher field with the first searcher username, the object type changes automatically from object to array type and keeps overwriting (i.e deleting the last username for the most recent one) like it was doing before

Comment: You should **not** add it as an array and after that add it as an object, you need to add it as an object in the first place and use `set()` method and pass `SetOptions.merge()` as the second argumennt. Try to make the update using a model class. Should work more easely, right?

Comment: Okay will try that and get back...thanks alot for your help

Comment: Thanks so much @Alex Mamo, it finally worked. Had to change this line ***db.collection("contact").document(document.getId()).update(Usermap).addOnSuccessListener()*** to ***db.collection("contact").document(document.getId()).update(Usermap, searcher).addOnSuccessListener()***. Thanks alot Alex Mamo for your help. God bless you.